# C# transmit exception from class to Form

Tags: c#, .net

How can I pass an error in the form of the class. When creating exemplar class.

Class:

```
class ThreadSafeLog
{
  public ThreadSafeLog()
  {
    try
    {
      if (!File.Exists(Path_))
      {
        using (File.Create(Path_)) { }
      }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      MessageBox.Show(e.Message);//error transmit exception to Form
    }
  }
}
```

Form:

```
ThreadSafeLog log = new ThreadSafeLog(
  @"R:\project\ThreadSafeLog\ThreadSafeLogTest\ThreadSafeLogTest\bin\");
```

Comment: I don't understand the question...

Answer (score 2):

Why would `ThreadSafeLog` be concerned with what the form that uses it is doing? How is it even supposed to know it's being used by a form? Catch the exception in the form instead.

```
class ThreadSafeLog
{
    public ThreadSafeLog()
    {
        if (!File.Exists(Path_))
        {
            using (File.Create(Path_)) { }
        }
    }
}
```

Form:

```
try
{
    ThreadSafeLog log = new ThreadSafeLog(
        @"R:\project\ThreadSafeLog\ThreadSafeLogTest\ThreadSafeLogTest\bin\");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
}
```

Though, as Adriano points out, you may also want to question why you're displaying internal error details directly to users.

Answer (score 0):

I would not notify log's users about an error inside the logger itself. Log is, usually, a subsystem that it's good to consider error-safe and thread-safe or you'll make your code a **messy**. Imagine:

```
try
{
    // Do something that may fail
}
catch (SomeException e)
{
    try
    {
        logger.Log(e);
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
        // Ooops, log doesn't work. What should I do?
        // Should I display a MessageBox?
    }
}
```

Your code will become quickly a messy (imagine to repeat the same check again and again for each trace log).

What I would do is to *ignore* (if possible) errors inside log function and to take another action instead. How? Just add an **event** to your log class (code is an example not for production!):

```
class Logger
{
    public event EventHandler<LogErrorEventArgs> Error;

    public void Log(Exception e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Try to write log somewhere...
        }
        catch (IOException internalException)
        {
            EventHandler<LogErrorEventArgs> error = Error;
            if (error != null)
                error(this, new LogErrorEventArgs(e, internalException);
        }
    }
}
```

In this way unhandled errors inside logger will go unnoticed (if this is applicable) or they may be handled (in the way it's appropriate, if there is a way). For example:

```
Logger logger = new Logger();
logger.Error += delegate(object sender, LogErrorEventArgs e)
{
    if (SystemInformation.UserInteractive)
        MessageBox.Show(e.ExceptionToLog.Message);
};
```

You may attach **multiple handlers** too (for example to log to Windows Log and notify user is session is interactive). When you use log you won't be aware it may fail (so you won't have to fill your code with `try`/`catch` everywhere) but if needed you may still be notified and errors inside log will be handled in a consistent manner.

Now let's rewrite the code in our first example like this:

```
try
{
    // Do something that may fail
}
catch (SomeException e)
{
    logger.Log(e);
}
```

Straight, right? I assumed logger will always write an exception (somehow) but it's easy to change code to handle a raw `String` instead. I omitted code for `LogErrorEventArgs` because pretty obvious anyway it may look like this:

```
class LogErrorEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public LogErrorEventArgs(
                            Exception exceptionToLog,
                            Exception internalLoggerException)
    {
        ExceptionToLog = exceptionToLog;
        InternalLoggerException = internalLoggerException;
    }

    public Exception ExceptionToLog
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public Exception InternalLoggerException
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Comment: @mzk just replace Logger with ThreadSafeLog and you're done. Don't forget to move File.Create() outside the constructor (or to pass a delegate to use for Error event as parameter). Usually it's not such nice idea to put code that may fail in this way (with _unpredictable_ exceptions) inside type constructor; I would use an initialization method or I'd create file first time it'll be used). Don't forget not only file creation may file but file write too (because of concurrency, because of permission, because of disk space...)